# Ubuntu 20.04 not booting stuck up at Failed to start GNOME Display Manager

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, gnome

Have tried nomodeset and the system is not booting up with multiple Failed to start services.
I tried multiple solutions from Google but still no luck.[image]

Answer (score 7):

This symptom may have multiple causes.

You can try: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell` . It may work accordingly to this website https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=122203

Another possibility is that you have run out of disk space (or your root partition has been compromised somehow). Check if you have some empty disk space left with `df -h` .

PS: to enable a terminal, hit Ctrl+Alt+F1 as soon as it gets stuck (try F2 if F1 is busy).

Comment: I had run out of disk space. Getting into terminal fixed it

Comment: @SimonFeatherstone could you please tell what commands did you enter?

Comment: ls,  cd, rm and rm -r

Comment: How do you guys get access to terminal ?

Comment: "hit Ctrl+Alt+F1 as soon as it gets stuck"

Answer (score 0):

There are **2 causes** for this problem:

1. **Too big log files in `/var/log` directory.**
2. **Disk full**

In the first case, in the `/var/log` folder, notice that some files are big and have the same size, for example,

- `messages.1`: **1.8 GB**
- `syslog.1`: **1.8 GB**
- `user.log.1`: **1.8 GB**.

In this case, even emptying the disk the problem continues. Some sources suggest not deleting these files, but just emptying it. This can be done in the terminal with the commands

```
$ > messages.1
$ > syslog.1
$ > user.log.1
```

If the disk is full, the fisrt case alone will not help, in this case you must access the disk through another partition or through an installer (bootable live USB) and empty the disk.

In my case, the black screen ends at the message

```
Starting Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen...
```